# Как обрезать изображение с лицом, найденным с помощью openCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Пытаюсь создать функцию, которая будет возвращать обрезанное изображение, если на нем есть лицо:

```
def upload_image(request):
data = {"success": False}
if request.method == 'POST':        
    form = forms.FileUploadForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES) 
    if form.is_valid():         
        image = grab_image(request.FILES['photo'])
        #fs = FileSystemStorage();
        #fs.save('d', image)
        #path_to_image = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\\' + image.name
        #uploaded_image = im.upload_image(path_to_image, title=image.name)
        #uploadet_link = uploaded_image.link
        #fs.delete(image.name)
        # convert the image to grayscale, load the face cascade detector,
        # and detect faces in the image
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(FACE_DETECTOR_PATH)
        rects = detector.detectMultiScale(image, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30), flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)#попытка сделать его цветым
        # construct a list of bounding boxes from the detection
        rects = [(int(x), int(y), int(x + w), int(y + h)) for (x, y, w, h) in rects]
        # update the data dictionary with the faces detected
        data.update({"num_faces": len(rects), "faces": rects, "success": True})
        if(len(rects) > 1):
            pass
        elif(len(rects) < 1):
            pass
        else:
            rect_list = list(map(int,rects[0]))
            crop_img = image[rect_list[1]:rect_list[1] + rect_list[3], rect_list[0]:rect_list[0] + rect_list[2]]#обрезка изображения по лицу
            print(type(crop_img))
            normal_image = Image.fromarray(crop_img).convert('RGB')#попытка сделать его цветым №2
            print(type(normal_image))
            normal_image.save( settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '\\' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg')
            #fs = FileSystemStorage();
            #fs.save(str(uuid.uuid4()), normal_image)
            crop_image()
    else:
        print(form.errors)
return JsonResponse(data)

def grab_image(stream):
    data = stream.read()
    # convert the image to a NumPy array and then read it into
    # OpenCV format
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(data), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
return image
```

Вот какое изображение я отправляю - [изображение на вход](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB98S.jpg) и вот, что получаю:
[получаю на выходе](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TO6M.jpg).

Метод для обрезки нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python). Но он как-то не правильно обрезает. Слишком большая ширина. Может проблема в самом определении лица? Пробовал и другие фотографии - тоже самое, в ширину разносит. Еще изображение возвращается в черно-белом, хотя пытаюсь его окрасить:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)#попытка сделать его цветым
normal_image = Image.fromarray(crop_img).convert('RGB')#попытка сделать его цветым №2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
FACE_DETECTOR_PATH=r'...\Library\etc\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'

def crop_face(img, scaleFactor=1.001,
              face_detector_path=FACE_DETECTOR_PATH):
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(FACE_DETECTOR_PATH)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        #img = cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        #roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        return roi_color

cropped = crop_face(img, scaleFactor=1.01)
cv2.imshow('1', cropped)

cv2.imwrite(r'с:/temp/res.png', cropped)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо. А можно как-то задать отступы, чтобы например [так](https://imgur.com/a/bAXU5IB) обрезалось. Вижу только один вариант:
`
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
` - rect`ы здесь менять. Насколько это верно? Еще я заливаю эти изображения на imgurl таким способом: сохраняю картинку на диск, в media папку, а потом вызываю метод im.upload_image(pyimgur библиотека), в который передаю путь к файлу и после удаляю изображение с диска. Можно ли как-то вытащить путь к изображению с памяти, чтобы с диском не работать?

Comment: @xomem, да, надо поэкспериментировать с roi_color, только наверное придётся ещё делать проверки, чтобы не выйти за пределы картинки.

Comment: а насколько верно все это делать во views.py. Может эти функции стоит вынести в отдельный файл/класс?

Comment: @xomem, это уже как говорится- «на вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные» ;)

Comment: По поводу чтения файла из памяти - попробуйте использовать [“io.BytesIO”](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) вместо пути к файлу

Comment: а вы бы как сделали?

Comment: @xomem, я не совсем понял вопрос

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90867/discussion-between-xomem-and-maxu).

Comment: @MaxU-stopgenocideofUA
Доброго дня.
У меня отчего то в Python 3.9.12 Conda  ваш код не воспроизводится.
В том смысле, что при отображении результирующего лица выводится черный прямоугольник и пайтон виснет.

Не знаете, что бы это могло быть?
Если что я- на винде